# Email address check with listbox items

Tags: c#, string, email, listbox

this is a homework Question, but I am really stuck and would appreciate your help. It's something small that will fix it i'm sure. The Q is using a regular expression, write a program that inputs a suggested email address and reports on whether or not it is accepted. Has to be of the form someone@someaddress.co.za. However there is a twist, allow the user to input special words such as webmaster, goverment in a listbox that will also reject the email address should it contain one of these words. Now I've tried the following, but it gives me "Invalid email" even if there is nothing in the listbox. the first if statement works perfectly.. My issue is getting those special words from the listbox to reject emails. Thanks a mil guys

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string special = null;
        special = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Text);
        string pattern = null;
        pattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, pattern)) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Valid Email address");

        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, special))
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Email address");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Email address");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps make a list of the words not allowed, and when you press the button, have it check to see if one of the words from the list are the input string?

Comment: Hmm I have made another list now that gets populated by listbox1, and had the new list as a parameter to check against the input string but no luck, unless im doing it wrong

Comment: Update your question with the new code

Comment: var myOtherList = listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

Comment: if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text,Convert.ToString( myOtherList)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Email address");
            }

Comment: Thanks hey, I appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, did you work it out?

Comment: Nps, not yet no.. Been working on another part of the assignment, word permutation. Giving it a go again tonight it's something small I know it, think I need to ditch the if statements though maybe try a loop.. Hmm

Comment: I figured it out :D used two while loops    while ((found == false) && ( index < lenght))
            {

                if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[index])))

                {
                    found = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Email address");
                }
                else
                {
                    index++;
                  
                }
               
            }

Comment: Thanks a mil for ur tips though

Comment: Glad you have it worked out, I recently moved houses, so I have only had my phone, good to hear it's sorted but :) interesting loop I must say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by defining at the top of your class your email address Pattern and a list of reserved words:

```
private const String PATTERN = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
private List<String> _reserved;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    _reserved = new List<string>();
    _reserved.Add("admin");
    _reserved.Add("administrator");
    _reserved.Add("government");
    _reserved.Add("helpdesk");
    _reserved.Add("webmaster");
}
```

Fill this list with whatever words are not allowed. Filling them in alphabetically will help maintain the list whenever something needs to be added or removed.

Above, the list is *pre-populated*, but it could also be any list that gets created by you as needed.

Checking to see if someone provided a reserved word by checking it against your list:

```
private bool Reserved(String email)
{
    var result = false;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        var lc = email.ToLower();
        result = _reserved.Any(x => -1 < x.IndexOf(lc));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The [Enumerable.Any Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) returns a Boolean value of True if any single item in the collection (denoted by `x` above) matches the following condition `-1 < x.IndexOf(lc))`.

The [String.IndexOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) returns "the zero-based index of the first occurrence" of whatever you pass in.

If your reserved words are all lower case and you pass in your variable as lower case, any IndexOf that is greater than -1 would be a failure (meaning, one of your reserved words matched).

Now, validating your email address has become a simple task:

```
public void ValidateEmail(String email)
{
    if (!Reserved(email))
    {
        var ok = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(email, PATTERN);
        if (!ok)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed Email Format");
        }
    } else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reserved Word");
    }
}
```

Comment: Jpcode, could you explain your linq part of the code please? I have never seen anything like this before. Thanks mate

Comment: Roughly translated, "any element (x) where the IndexOf(email_lowerCase) is Greater Than -1". The [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) method returns `-1` if there is no match. So you want to know if [Linq.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) item in the collection matches the email (lower case) you pass in.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace emailCheck
{

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool found = false;
        int lenght, index;
        index = 0;
        lenght = listBox1.Items.Count;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[index]);
        string pattern = null;
        pattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";

        while ((found == false) && ( index < lenght))
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[index])))
            {
                found = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Email address");
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        while (found == false)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, pattern))
            {
                found = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Valid Email address");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Invalid Email address");
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

  }
}
```